# Customize Bootstrap datatable filter filed and put place holder

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to customize my Bootstrap datatable search field and needs to put placeholder in it. And also I need to hide pagination drop down and change the position of search filed to left. Please find the attached screenshot for more clarification.

I have tried following code using jQuery for placeholder but it did not work:

```
$('#demo-dtable-01_filter input').attr('placeholder','Type in customer name, date or amount');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution and at last its working properly

```
$('#demo-dtable-01_filter').find('input[type=text]').attr('placeholder','Type in customer name, date or amount');
$('#demo-dtable-01_filter').find('input[type=text]').addClass('span8');
$('.dt_header>.row-fluid').children().first().addClass('hide');
$('.dt_header>.row-fluid').children().eq(1).css('margin-left','0px');
$('.dt_header>.row-fluid').children().eq(1).children().eq(0).addClass('pull-left span12');
$('.dataTables_filter label').css('width','392px');
$('.estimatedbrd .dataTables_filter label').css('float','left');
```

Now its looks like attached file [image]

Answer (score 3):

FYI, If You want move position of field search to left, you can user [Dom Positioning](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "dom": '<"pull-left"f>rt<"bottom"ip>'
    });
    $('#example').removeClass('display').addClass('table table-striped table-bordered');
    $('.dataTables_filter input[type="search"]').attr('placeholder','Type in customer name, date or amount').css({'width':'250px','display':'inline-block'});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YfhNA/

Answer (score 0):

You can assign placeholder to datatable search field as given below.

```
$('#example_filter.dataTables_filter input[type="search"]').attr('placeholder', 'Search By ...');
```

where

```
<table id="example"> ..... </table>
```

`**Note:**`

1. Datatable API automatically create filter for given table id by appending suffix as '_filter'.
2. Input Type must be 'search' `input[type="search"]'` .(Default type can be inspect in the browser)